# Using if else in c macros

Tags: c, macros

i'm trying to define the following macro:

```
#define UTF8_2B(c) if((0xc0 & c) == 0xc0){return 1;}
```

But i'm met with the error:

```
expected expression before ‘if’
```

The macro is called like so:

```
int i = UTF8_2B(c);
```

Where c is an unsigned char read from a file.

Why does this happen? Can you not use if else statements in macros?
Also, I've read that it's not a good idea to use semicolon in your macros, but i didn't understand why. 
I'm new to c so the more thorough the answer the better.

Comment: How do you use the macro? (And, perhaps more importantly: What do you want to achieve?)

Comment: show the context where you're calling this macro

Comment: Macros do text substitutions; you couldn't write `variable = if (condition) …` directly, so you can't use a macro that does it either. You're missing the else value too. And `return` is wholly inappropriate in context.  Remember: macro is text substitution.  After preprocessing, the code must be valid C.

Comment: Not only that, even the logic is wrong. What should happen in the `else` case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning the result of your macro to a variable. You cannot do that with the current macro (`return` returns from the current function, and doesn't return something to be assigned to `i`: so not what you want).

If you're using `gcc`, you can view what your pre-processed code looks like with the `-E` command line.

So you *can* use `if` in macros, but not in macros that are used like functions, which are supposed to return a value.

Moreover:

- if `c` is a complex expression, operator precedence could make the macro generate wrong code
- the macro should provide a way to require semicolon, so IDEs and human readers see that as a normal function

I'd propose a simple test instead (which yields 1 if true, 0 otherwise), which meets the "need semicolon" standard and is safe to use with a complex `c` expression:

```
#define UTF8_2B(c) ((0xc0 & (c)) == 0xc0)
```

Answer (score 4):

C (and C++) preprocessor macros are essentially "copy-paste" with argument substitution. So your code becomes:

```
int i = if((0xc0 & c) == 0xc0){return 1;}
```

And this is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator exists for this purpose. Assuming you want 1 if true and 0 if false, the correct macro is:

```
 #define UTF8_2B(c) (((c) & 0xC0) == 0xC0 ? 1 : 0)
```

Now you can assign the result. Using `return` in a macro will return from the enclosing function, not from the macro, and is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: typo: `C0` -> `0xC0`, also the ternary operator is redundant: the comparison already evaluates to `0` or `1`.